# DES decrypt/encrypt java to python (help in translate)

Tags: java, python, base64, translate, des

I need to translate a short code in java to python 3.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class DesEncrypterPdys {
    private static DesEncrypterPdys desEncrypter;
    private static Cipher ecipher;
    private static Cipher dcipher;

    private DesEncrypterPdys() throws DesEncrypterException{
        try {
            if(ecipher == null || dcipher == null){
                String cryptoKey;
                cryptoKey = "RAMPOLO S.O. Plokity Lopiokiujhygh ;)";

                SecretKey k = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(cryptoKey.getBytes()));

                ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
                dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        }
    }

    public static DesEncrypterPdys getInstance() throws DesEncrypterException{
        if (desEncrypter == null || ecipher == null || dcipher == null) {
            desEncrypter = new DesEncrypterPdys();
        }
        return desEncrypter;
    }

    public String encrypt(String str) throws DesEncrypterException{
        try {
            if(str == null) return null;
            // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

            // Encrypt
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

            // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string

            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String str) throws DesEncrypterException{
        try {
            if(str == null) return null;
            // Decode base64 to get bytes
            byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);

            // Decrypt
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

            // Decode using utf-8
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            throw new DesEncrypterException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Im tried to use something like this:

```
import pyDes as pds
import base64 as b64


cryptoKey = "RAMPOLO S.O. Plokity Lopiokiujhygh ;)";
data = b" " # here should be a data for decrypting

k = pds.des(cryptoKey, pds.ECB, b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=pds.PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt(data)
print("Encrypted: %r" % d)
print("Decrypted: %r" % k.decrypt(d))
print(b64.b64encode(d))
```

but unfortunately no luck:/

What I want to receive is a short program to encrypt and decode passwords. unfortunately I encountered a problem with too long cryptokey(?). Once I was able to translate an analogous piece of code but it was probably a matter of luck that old case was corresponded to the case from the pydes documentation. Now is different...
Can some one help me with translation this java code to python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your code the error returned is:

```
>>> import pyDes as pds
>>> import base64 as b64
>>> cryptoKey = "RAMPOLO S.O. Plokity Lopiokiujhygh ;)"
>>> data = b"qwertyuiop" # Random gibberish
>>> k = pds.des(cryptoKey, pds.ECB, b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=pds.PAD_PKCS5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyDes.py", line 400, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long.")
ValueError: Invalid DES key size. Key must be exactly 8 bytes long.
```

if you take a look at the Github documentation for [pyDES](https://github.com/twhiteman/pyDes) it specifies that for DES encryption the key should be 8bytes long, yours is way longer. You need to use a shorter key, then it works fine.

```
>>> k = pds.des('12345678', pds.ECB, b"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=pds.PAD_PKCS5)
>>> k
<pyDes.des object at 0x7fc4ade1f9d0>
```

Important sidenote, from a security point of view you should avoid using DES as it's completely broken for today's standards, even the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Security_and_cryptanalysis) (which is not a great source of cryptographic knowledge) shows that DES breaking is feasible. Also ECB mode is broken as it doesn't provide any security guarantees because each block is encrypted in the exact same way, check [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption).